# English idioms and locutions based on Celtic culture or languages

Tags: idioms, british-english, idiom-requests

Are there any widely-spread English idioms with Celtic cultural references?

**To be more specific:**
Let's suppose that Crossing the Rubicon is the idiom based on Roman Empire cultural reference. Is there something similar about Celts?

Edited the post to eliminate idioms with just Celtic words. 
Currently there are 3 useful idioms from comments and answer:

1. Kilkinny cats
2. Gift of the gab
3. Barnley stone

Comment: your questions will probably be closed because the answer is too broad, but any idioms containing "daddy" would fit (sugar daddy, dad bod etc.) also "basket" (don't put your eggs in one basket)  here pick any of these hundreds words and you'll probably find an expression or idiom containing it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_English_words_of_Celtic_origin#Lists_of_English_words_derived_from_Celtic_languages

Comment: I think you're going to have to be a bit more specific than that. There are many words in English that are borrowed from Celtic languages, including quite a few slang terms (does that count as ‘locutions’?). Probably not that many full-blown idioms. What exactly counts as a “Celtic cultural reference”? Does “You can't kill an Irishman with alcohol” count? How about when J.K. Rowling for her _Harry Potter_ series invents phrases like “Merlin’s beard!”, does that count?

Comment: Lots of [words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_Brittonic_origin), such as *whiskey*, *shillelagh*, *brat*; lots of placenames and placename elements, such as *Avon*, *coombe*, *glen*. And there's growing sympathy for the notion that the progressive and existential constructions are grounded in British syntax. But I agree, this is too broad to be answered adequately.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks for you attention. _Merlin's beard_ is the closest thing to what I need. More specifically, let's suppose that _Crossing the Rubicon_ is the idiom based on Roman Empire cultural reference. Is there something similar about Celts?

Comment: "fighting like two kilkenny cats", "gift of the gab", something about snakes and St. Patrick, [LMGTFY](https://www.google.com/search?q=irish+expressions)

Comment: @P.O. Are you saying that 'daddy' and basket are primarily Irish? I find that hard to believe.

Comment: @mitch Irish and Celtic are not the same thing , Irish is one type  of Celtic language. Gaelic, Britonic,  Gaulish, Irish, Scotich, Mansk etc. are all celtic languages , according to WP the origin of these words are Britonic. I don't even know if it's true, but the point was to illustrate that the question was too broad.

Comment: @P.O. Sure, Celtic. Re daddy, I saw no reference to Celtic at WP or Wiktionary. Re basket, if wiktionary can be believed, it's most recently from 'Anglo-Norman' so any phrases would come a long from Anglo-Norman culture, not the three steps removed originating Celtic. But yes, in the end, too broad and should be a WP 'list of' page.

Comment: @mitch https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_Brittonic_origin#daddy

Comment: @P.O. Follow the references all the way. ['basket' from etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=basket) ". So whoever did the wikipedia entry was a little aspirational: "origin obscure despite much speculation". What about 'daddy'?

Comment: 3 words down from Basket in the same link.

Comment: Give me a break! Just because a word has a Latin root, it does not qualify as something comparable to "crossing the Rubicon" Though I've never heard "fighting like two killkenny cats," I'm guessing that this is a good answer as is the answer below But before you close the question on the grounds that there are too many acceptable answers, show me a few more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A person being full of blarney. Persons that kiss the Blarney stone are given the gift of gab, according to legend. "Gab" itself is middle English, but the stone is located at Blarney Castle in Ireland. Blarney became a stand-in for foolish flattery, and eventually for nonsense or B.S. (why is this a legal acronym?) in general.

Comment: If no one comes with more idioms, this will be an accepted answer. Thank you.